# How to pass variables between pthreads?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have two types of threads, one student the other librarian. Also I have a list of struct which holds the basic info like book name, ISBN, publishing year regarding to each books.(which is a shared resource between threads) I want to pass the pointer of a certain book in a student thread/routine to a librarian thread using condition variables. (so that a librarian could reserve the book for the student by means of signaling) How can I accomplish this is or is this even the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use pipes `man 2 pipe`.

Performance wise faster, but far more complicated ways are to use a virtual ring buffer `man 3 vrb` (userland pipe) or any other message passing middleware.

Answer (score 1):

If these are [*threads*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) (using pthread library) in the *same* process, you can share data since the [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) is common to them. However, be aware of synchronization issues.

A common way to do that is to use a mutex for every (read or write) access to that common data. Perhaps also use condition variables for synchronization (i.e. thread A needing to tell thread B that something significant changed).

Read a good [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) (and [this](http://randu.org/tutorials/threads/) perhaps also).

Answer (score 1):

> is this even the right way to go about it?

Your example is very artificial... the only reason why you would use threads and some strange local variable list for this, is because some teacher tells you to do so. So no, this is not the right way to implement a program to be used in the real world.

In the real world, things like these would almost certainly be implemented through a database, where the DBMS handles the accessing of individual posts. Most likely in some kind of client/server system, where there is a client used by the librarian. I don't see why the student would even be part of the system, except as a data post over who borrowed the book.